# How to determine which process in an array was started first?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, process

I've made a list of processes with the same process name as the current one. Here is how the list is made:

```
Process curr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(curr.ProcessName);
```

My objective is to get the first process that was started and store only him in a new variable. I've tried some things, but I have no idea on what to do.

```
// procs[1].StartTime.Ticks ????
```

The question is how can I get the process with the lowest start time in an array of processes?

Comment: Think you are looking for the [Process.StartTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.starttime?view=netframework-4.8) property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already identified the property that you should use and it is called StartTime.
Now, to find the lowest start time in your processes array, you could simply use OrderBy from the Linq namespace and then get the first element from the ordered sequence.

```
Process curr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();  
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(curr.ProcessName);
var theFirst = procs.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

You could also use First() instead of FirstOrDefault() because at least one process with the same name of the current process should exist.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong in this answer to merit a downvote. Hope the downvoter cares to explain.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I was trying to use For (var i = 0; i < procs.lenght; i++) and doing it one by one, but it was lagging the program.